# I want to add clear float to the "Read more link" in wordpress (loop)

Tags: wordpress

I want to add clear float to the "Read more link" (it says "Läs mer" on my site, swedish) 
in Wordpress (loop).

Here is my loop,

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-3'); ?>
        <ul id="customStart" class="group">
             <?php query_posts('showposts=55&cat=5,');
                        if (have_posts()) : ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <li>
                       <div class="blogPostInfo"><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?><div class="fltLeft"> | <?php the_category(', ') ?></div></div>
                      <div id="startBg">
                       <?php the_post_thumbnail('start-pic'); ?>
                        </div>
                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                         <?php the_content( __( '<span class="meta-nav"> Läs mer</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                     </ul>
                     <?php endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

http://www.missbee.se/eliteRehab2/

---

Look at the lower part of the site to see to find the buttons 
that I want to clear ;O)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you edit the CSS file and add the

`clear:both` or `clear:left` or `clear:right` property

for the `.meta-nav` class?

Comment: Have you inspected the elements in Firebug or Chrome dev tools? Is it getting over-written by something else? Try `clear:both !important`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
.meta-nav
{clear:left | both | right;
}
```

to your `style.css` in your theme css sheet.